# How to determine the cause of a performance degradation?

Tags: google-app-engine

I am playing with GAE and made a very compact application that gets tiny requests and outputs tiny responses at a constant rate (from a program that uses cURL and a loop).

It's not dealing with a UI and it's not meant to be called from a browser, it's simply receiving POST requests, doing some processing and outputting light data as ASCII text.

I've managed to optimize my app a bit so that the average latency is usually 20-30 ms and it's been working great so far, a single instance could probably manage easily a dozen of queries per second because of the very low latency.

This morning however, for about 40 minutes, there was a big spike in performance degradation and the application started to take 20,000 to 30,000 ms to handle a request, see here : https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYxmv.png .
The GAE app code was not altered during this time nor the program that makes the requests.

How can I know what was the cause of this and if it will happen again in the future?
I checked in the logs and nothing looked wrong and there is no way to contact Google on this.

My app is very sensitive to latency and all requests should be handled as fast as possible and certainly under 1 second.

I set the Min Pending Latency at 10ms in the Admin panel of my application but is there a way to reduce the max timeout of a request? It is 60 seconds by default I think.

---

Edit : Here are [other charts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LKzi.png) where we can see what was affeted was 'API calls CPU' and 'Active instances' but I am not sure how that tells me what went wrong...

---

Edit2 : Here are some log entries for requests that happened during the problematic period :

```
69.165.137.199 - - [23/Nov/2011:06:56:11 -0800] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 287 - - "app.appspot.com" ms=36378 cpu_ms=258 api_cpu_ms=98 cpm_usd=0.007259 instance=00c61b117cd98a4e8f9d6c0215d5e14c3336
69.165.137.199 - - [23/Nov/2011:06:55:32 -0800] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 287 - - "app.appspot.com" ms=34584 cpu_ms=125 api_cpu_ms=98 cpm_usd=0.003555 instance=00c61b117cd98a4e8f9d6c0215d5e14c3336
```

Comment: Can you include some log entries for requests that were slow in your question?

Comment: Hi, unfortunately there were no log entries during the turbulent period of time, no info or errors logging happened...

Comment: Really? Are you sure you set the log viewer to 'all requests', not 'minimum severity: error' (which is the default)? Can you paste the two log entries from immediately before and after?

Comment: @Nick : Hi and thanks for your comments, I found log entries for requests that happened during the problematic period, I added them (see Edit2 above)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some things to try:

- Try to deploy it again under a different name (make that the new default) and see if performance comes back.  If it does then there may be something that causes it to slow down as it runs.
- Check how big your datastore is.  You may have some queries that are only slow when testing with a large dataset.
- Download appstats [here is a tutorial](http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2010/03/easy-performance-profiling-with.html) and follow this guide to performance profiling
- If you are using memcache check that you are returning data from it instead of doing another datastore query
- If you are using task queues, make sure one didn't get stuck.  You can manually run them from the admin page.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will try appstats. My app should not be slowing down as it is running because the performance came back after about 40 minutes of struggling (now it's running perfectly fine again). My datastore is tiny so it should not be related and I am using memcache effectively (tested) to retrieve data from the memcache/datastore. No task queues are used. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Did you check from the logs where time was spent? In CPU, pending state or in API?. In my experience datastore just sometimes does that without obvious reason so there isn't necessarily anything wrong with your app. Try high replication datastore  if stable latency is important though it has slightly higher minimum latency.

Comment: Hi and thanks, see my edit to find other info that could be useful...but I am not sure where to get more details about historical datastore operations or any other info, are you? In the 'Logs' tab, I can only see messages (Error, info, debug) and none are meaningful or connected to the situation that occured.

Comment: You can click at least recent log entries in admin console and see stuff like this: ms=57 cpu_ms=47 api_cpu_ms=8 cpm_usd=0.001365. Based on your chart I would blame datastore.

Comment: Hi, I found some logs for requests that happened during the problematic period, I added them (see Edit2 above)

Comment: CPU and API times are low, so likely issue was Datastore latency.